# docker + phpmyadmin не входит под ‘user@localhost’

Tags: phpmyadmin, docker

Запускаю docker, создаю в контейнерах nginx, mysql, php-fpm, phpmyadmin.

Все работает, но проблема с пользователем возникает в phpmyadmin.
phpmyadmin не дает войти под пользователем `user@localhost`, но пускает под пользователем `user@%`, причем через командную строку mysql все отлично работает.

В принципе можно и так работать, но хотелось бы разобраться:

- Почему не пускает под `localhost`?
- Какие последствия если работа под пользователем c хостом `%`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634124/4794368

Comment: нужно зайти в контейнер докер из и добавить логин пароль

Comment: нет, ссылка не дает ответа, она поясняет разницу  данных пользователей в общих чертах, в данном случае нюанс использования именно через docker думаю. Добавление логина и пароля в environment так же не актуально, т.к. планируется что в данном контейнере будут крутиться несколько баз и доступ будет у каждого пользователя к своей базе.